# JavaScript: object extract and update key values

Tags: javascript

I have object of customer information. From that information I want to extract `firstName`, `lastName`, `size` and `weight`. After extract that data, in `size` key's value I want to add `cm` and  in `weight` key's value I want to add `kg`. I successfully extract object from non-required data. I am having difficulties to manipulate the `size` and `weight` values.

**This is what I have done so far**

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
  const filterObj = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) =>
      ["fn", "ln", "size", "weight"].includes(key)
    )
  );

  if (filterObj.size) {
    return {
      ["size"]: filterObj.size.toString().concat("cm"),
      ...filterObj,
    };
  } else if (filterObj.weight) {
   
    return {
      ["weight"]: filterObj.weight.toString().concat("kg"),
      ...filterObj,
    };
  } else {
    return filterObj;
  }
}

console.log(
  myFunction({
    fn: "Martin",
    ln: "Harper",
    age: 26,
    email: "martin.harper@test.de",
    weight: 102,
  }),
  "expected result: {fn: 'Martin', ln: 'Harper', weight: '102kg'}"
);

console.log(
  myFunction({fn: 'Matthew', ln: 'Müller', age: 19, email: 'matthew@mueller.de'}),
  "expected result: {fn: 'Matthew', ln: 'Müller'}"
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be vastly simplified with a simple lookup

```js
const filterObject = { "fn": "", "ln": "", "size": "cm", "weight": "kg" };
const fKeys = Object.keys(filterObject);
const myFunction = obj => {
  const newObj = {}; // or even a reduce
  fKeys.forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key]) newObj[key] = `${obj[key]}${filterObject[key]}`;
  });
  return newObj;
};

console.log(
  myFunction({
    fn: "Martin",
    ln: "Harper",
    age: 26,
    email: "martin.harper@test.de",
    weight: 102,
  }),
  "expected result: {fn: 'Martin', ln: 'Harper', weight: '102kg'}"
);
```

To pass your test:

```
function myFunction(obj) {
  const filterObject = { "fn": "", "ln": "", "size": "cm", "weight": "kg" };
  const fKeys = Object.keys(filterObject);
  const newObj = {}; 
  fKeys.forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key]) newObj[key] = `${obj[key]}${filterObject[key]}`
  });
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: I was testing in here, but it failed: https://www.jschallenger.com/javascript-fundamentals/javascript-objects/extracting-information-ojects/

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/o1r03pvq/

Comment: It wanted some semicolons. See my update

Comment: Thanks a lot!For learning purpose, what was wrong in my code?

Comment: I have no idea. I did not try to fix your code since it was too big to be efficient. The solution is even simpler than mine: `function myFunction(obj) {  return {  fn: obj.fn,  ln: obj.ln,  ...(obj.size && { size: \`${obj.size}cm\` }),  ...(obj.weight && { weight: \`${obj.weight}kg\` }) }; }`

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the spread operator first and provide your override *after* spreading the whole object.

So your return statement here

```
{
  ["weight"]: filterObj.weight.toString().concat("kg"),
  ...filterObj,
}
```

...by swapping the order, would become:

```
{
  ...filterObj,
  ["weight"]: filterObj.weight.toString().concat("kg"),
}
```

I've made a few other optimisations to your code:

- no need to use `else if` and `else` if the previous chain ends with a `return` statement
- I used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make the string concatenation (appending the unit) a little more readable
- you can name keys directly on the object:

```
weight: filterObj.weight...
```

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
  const filterObj = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) =>
      ["fn", "ln", "size", "weight"].includes(key)
    )
  );

  if (filterObj.size) {
    return {
      ...filterObj,
      size: `${filterObj.size}cm`,
    };
  }
  if (filterObj.weight) {
    return {
      ...filterObj,
      weight: `${filterObj.weight}kg`,
    };
  }

  return filterObj;
}

console.log(
  myFunction({
    fn: "Martin",
    ln: "Harper",
    age: 26,
    email: "martin.harper@test.de",
    weight: 102,
  })
);
```

Comment: I was testing in here, but it failed: https://www.jschallenger.com/javascript-fundamentals/javascript-objects/extracting-information-ojects/

Comment: The test is crap. The code works

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
function otherFunction(obj){
    const {fn,ln,size, weight} = obj;
    let o={"fn":fn,"ln":ln}
    if(size!=undefined)
        o.size=size+"cm"
    if(weight!=undefined)
        o.weight=weight+"kg"
    return o;
}
otherFunction({ n: "Martin",ln: "Harper",age: 26, email: "martin.harper@test.de",weight: 102,})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
  const filterObj = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => ["fn", "ln", "size", "weight"].includes(key))
  );

  Object.keys(filterObj).map(function(i) {
    if (i == 'weight') {
      filterObj[i] = filterObj[i] + 'kg';
    } else if (i == 'size') {
      filterObj[i] = filterObj[i] + 'cm';
    }
  });

  return filterObj;
}

console.log(
  myFunction({
    fn: 'Martin',
    ln: 'Harper',
    age: 26,
    email: 'martin.harper@test.de',
    weight: 102
  }), {
    fn: 'Martin',
    ln: 'Harper',
    weight: '102kg'
  }
)
```

Comment: This one passes the tests too